# Kurento ошибка туториала

Tags: docker, spring-boot, видео

Делаю студенческий проект на андроид, нужно реализовать видеосвязь. Выбрал для реализации Kurento. Поставил докер и запустил контейнер. Насколько могу судить сделал это правильно. Далее скачал туториалы с гита. Пытаюсь запустить - выпадает ошибка. Пытался открывать закрывать порты, менять проперти, но ничего не выходит. Прошу помощи. Если есть альтернатива куренто, то я бы рассмотрел. Заранее спасибо за помощь

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSocketHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'webSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'handler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kurento'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kurentoClient' defined in org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kurento.client.KurentoClient]: Factory method 'kurentoClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.kurento.commons.exception.KurentoException: Exception connecting to KMS
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application.main(Application.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'webSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'handler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kurento'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kurentoClient' defined in org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kurento.client.KurentoClient]: Factory method 'kurentoClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.kurento.commons.exception.KurentoException: Exception connecting to KMS
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'handler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kurento'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kurentoClient' defined in org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kurento.client.KurentoClient]: Factory method 'kurentoClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.kurento.commons.exception.KurentoException: Exception connecting to KMS
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$697f475c.handler() ~[classes/:na]
        at org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application.registerWebSocketHandlers(Application.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketConfiguration.registerWebSocketHandlers(DelegatingWebSocketConfiguration.java:51) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurationSupport.initHandlerRegistry(WebSocketConfigurationSupport.java:55) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurationSupport.webSocketHandlerMapping(WebSocketConfigurationSupport.java:43) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bda373b4.CGLIB$webSocketHandlerMapping$3() ~[spring-websocket-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bda373b4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ff8dcf3d.invoke() ~[spring-websocket-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bda373b4.webSocketHandlerMapping() ~[spring-websocket-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kurentoClient' defined in org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kurento.client.KurentoClient]: Factory method 'kurentoClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.kurento.commons.exception.KurentoException: Exception connecting to KMS
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kurento.client.KurentoClient]: Factory method 'kurentoClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.kurento.commons.exception.KurentoException: Exception connecting to KMS
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.kurento.commons.exception.KurentoException: Exception connecting to KMS
        at org.kurento.client.KurentoClient.(KurentoClient.java:259) ~[kurento-client-6.16.0.jar:6.16.0]
        at org.kurento.client.KurentoClient.create(KurentoClient.java:129) ~[kurento-client-6.16.0.jar:6.16.0]
        at org.kurento.client.KurentoClient.create(KurentoClient.java:116) ~[kurento-client-6.16.0.jar:6.16.0]
        at org.kurento.client.KurentoClient.create(KurentoClient.java:111) ~[kurento-client-6.16.0.jar:6.16.0]
        at org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application.kurentoClient(Application.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$697f475c.CGLIB$kurentoClient$2() ~[classes/:na]
        at org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$697f475c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$82f36496.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.kurento.tutorial.helloworld.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$697f475c.kurentoClient() ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 61 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.kurento.jsonrpc.JsonRpcException: [KurentoClient]  Exception connecting to WebSocket server ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
        at org.kurento.jsonrpc.client.AbstractJsonRpcClientWebSocket.internalConnectIfNecessary(AbstractJsonRpcClientWebSocket.java:735) ~[kurento-jsonrpc-client-6.16.0.jar:6.16.0]
        at org.kurento.jsonrpc.client.AbstractJsonRpcClientWebSocket.connectIfNecessary(AbstractJsonRpcClientWebSocket.java:847) ~[kurento-jsonrpc-client-6.16.0.jar:6.16.0]
        at org.kurento.jsonrpc.client.AbstractJsonRpcClientWebSocket.connect(AbstractJsonRpcClientWebSocket.java:678) ~[kurento-jsonrpc-client-6.16.0.jar:6.16.0]
        at org.kurento.client.KurentoClient.(KurentoClient.java:251) ~[kurento-client-6.16.0.jar:6.16.0]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
    Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:8888
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:660) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:875) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
    
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: SpringBoot и Kurento каждый в своём контейнере или только Kurento? Порт в Докере правильно открыт? У тебя СпрингБут не может к нему приконнектиться `Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:8888`

Comment: В контейнере только куренто. Про порт не знаю. Я решил проблему установив дополнительно убунту и на ней все запустилось отлично